# How to notice if a UITableViewCell has left the visible area?

Tags: ios, uitableview, visibility

I'm stuck with the problem that I want to know in my UITableView if a specific UITableViewCell, let's say the first, is still visible or already off the visible area.
I would also be ok to know if the cell of interest is now beeing reused at an other indexPath of the table.

One of my - later and frustrated approaches - was to have a thread that knows the first cell object and frequently pings it to check if a value I did set in the cell changed. Obviously a not so good solution.

Andy ideas how to do this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that UITableView is UIScrollView subclass and its delegate also confirms to UIScrollViewDelegate protocol as well.

So in your table delegate you can implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method and check contentOffset - if it's more then first cell height then first cell is not visible. You can also get the array off all currently visible cells using `-visibleCells` method, but I think knowing contentOffset should be enough.

Comment: You absolutely helped my out! Thanks a lot for that adivce!

Comment: Careful with contentOffset and rowHeight -- there could be table headers and section headers and footers involved as well which would make the comparison much more tricky.